# AmazonS3Client hanging at PutObject

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Starting last week, uploading files to our S3 storage (caringo swarm) has started to randomly hang (more often than not) at `s3Client.PutObject()`, and I am struggling to identify a resolution. I have a very simple repro from my desktop.  After about 10 min, the file does successfully upload, but it should be sub-second response time.

- This is a .NET Framework
- The issue happens with both .Net Framework 4.7.2 and 4.8
- I am using latest AWSSDK.Core and AWSSDK.S3 NuGet packages
- Manually uploading files from the vendor's web site works fine, just not from code
- All our environments (prod, QA and my desktop/local environment) point to same storage system, just different buckets

I can reproduce the issue 9 out of 10 times with the code below.  I even tried using `s3Client.PutObjectAsync()` but same results.

Any ideas?

```
private const string key = "<key>";
private const string secret = "<secret>";
private const string file = @"C:\Users\file1.jpg";
private const string url = "https://someurl.com";
private const string bucket = "bucket1";
private const string destFile = "file1.jpg";

private static void RunSync()
{
    AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
    config.ServiceURL = url;
    try
    {
        using (AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(key, secret, config))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucket,
                    CannedACL = (S3CannedACL.PublicRead),
                    Key = destFile,
                    InputStream = fs
                };
                PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.PutObject(request);
                Console.WriteLine("Status Code: " + response.HttpStatusCode);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I also tried the sample code from S3 site [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html) but still, it even then it hung up at

```
// Initiate the upload.
InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse =
            await s3Client.InitiateMultipartUploadAsync(initiateRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a Caringo Swarm issue - the authentication with AWS had changed, requiring a recycle of their services, which resolved everything on our end.